Ghusl and 3x sunnah acts
Salam aleykium, i've an question about ghusl. How i know its wajib to rinse nose and mouth and to wash the whole Body.
But my question is about the nose when i didnt wash it correctly on the first try but on the second and third i did it correctly is my ghusl valid? Or is Always the first try wajib? How i know 3x is sunnah, so If i make an mistake on the first try, do i have to repeat ghusl from new?
